# Acer Aspire One 756 and windows 7

Tags: laptop

I bought laptop Acer Aspire One 756 containing windows 7. Can anybody give hints, how to reinstall the windows and divide hard disc into partitions C and D? Thank you for hints.

Recards

Comment: Not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It cant be programmed which means this is not the forum for this question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple search would have lead you to plenty of tutorials, such as the following:

- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52291-partition-hard-drive-windows-7-install.html
- http://www.petri.co.il/creating-a-partition-during-windows-7-installation.htm